# Access is denied when trying to CreateFileAsync in InstalledLocation StorageFolder?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I got Access is denied when trying to CreateFileAsync in InstalledLocation StorageFolder

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("fileNmae", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Also I tried

```
var storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///");
```

And got "value does not fall within the expected range"

I can go around and `CreateFileAsync` in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` then `CopyAsync` to InstalledLocation StorageFolder?

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("fileName", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

StorageFolder installedLocationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var result = await file.CopyAsync(installedLocationFolder, "fileName", Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

but `CreateFileAsync` in InstalledLocation StorageFolder gives Access denied ?
is that because of security reason or I'm coding something wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The app's install directory is a read-only location. In addition, it would not be recommended that you write data files to the installed location.  If you need to store data this is for the application's use only, you should use

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

or

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder temporaryFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
```

depending on the lifetime of the data.

Comment: If I'm not wrong the install directory and its sub directories are read-only locations.